# React, custom package, cannot find module

Tags: npm-install, modulenotfounderror

It was necessary to use a custom package without uploading to npm. I created a mini project with a couple of simple components. In the root index.ts exported the components.

`export { Comp1, Comp2 };`

Made npm pack - got test-ui-1.0.0.tgz moved .tgz to the main project(cra) folder in the root. Made npm install test-ui-1.0.0.tgz. A package has been added to the dependencies

`"test-ui": "file:test-ui-1.0.0.tgz",`

I tried to get the component in the right place

`import { Comp1 } from 'test-ui';`

I get an error - *Cannot find module 'test-ui' or its corresponding type declarations.*

**Tell me what could be the reason? Please**

webpack.config.js in pack app

````
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
    },
    externals: {
        react: "react",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                use: ["ts-loader"],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: ["@svgr/webpack", "url-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
};```

In main project tsconfig.json 

```{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
    "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
    "include": ["src", "craco.config.js", "tsconfig.paths.json"]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been determined. It was necessary to do in the npx webpack package dist appears and after doing the npm pack

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).